# redirect non-index page requests to hash links with .htaccess

Tags: ajax, regex, .htaccess, redirect, hash

i'm weak in regular expressions, i need to redirect any **FileName.htm** or **FileName.html** page request to **./#FileName**, only if the request is incoming from an outside link. These files will all reside in the root directory.

this is what i have so far. it gives me errors : (

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.html$|!index.htm$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.html$ /#$1 [NE, R]
```

*the first line* makes sure only index files are not redirected.
*the second line* doesn't redirect if the request is coming from an unknown referrer
*the third line* excludes my domain from the redirection rule
*the fourth line* redirects it to the hash link.

which doesn't seem to work.
and please if there is a more efficient way to write this, i would be grateful. 
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.html?$ /#$1 [NE,R]
```

Comment: Hi!
i added your code to my .htaccess file and made a test page for it here 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/428209/test-link.html
and even tho the error is gone, it doesn't seem to redirect. 
thank you : )

Comment: you're right!  
i was using "open in new tab" ah that's why.. and may i know what the ß does in "wwwß"? i googled for it without any success. 
thank youuUU!!!

Comment: @Mohammad: Just a typo. On german keyboards the \ character resides on the same key as the ß character but needs the modifying key *AltGr* to be pressed. I just missed to press that key.