# Help with .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect pages like

http://www.domain.com/article/12345 to http://www.domain.com/page/#/obj12345

12345 could be any number.

What should I write in .htaccess to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Swfaddress incorporates this kind of behaviour. They use basic .htaccess rules, in combination with php. See http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/samples/ajax/ for an example.

Comment: Hm.. I need something more simple, a string in .htaccess file. Something like Redirect 301 /article/12345 http://www.domain.com/pages/index/#/obj12345, but to work with any number.

Comment: Ok, wasn't really sure if u can use the # serverside. I guess u can [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999969/redirect-non-index-page-requests-to-hash-links-with-htaccess

Comment: I hope 301 redirect is for permanent move that is domain to other domain. but you can redirect with in the same domain but can not be dynamic.