# Redirect AJAX page requests to canonical links with .htaccess

Tags: ajax, regex, .htaccess, redirect, hash

I'm coding a site that makes heavy use of AJAX to load pages for users with JavaScript, but I also want it to be friendly for users with JavaScript disabled or unavailable.  I've covered all the basics; for example, all my links point to canonical links, and JavaScript loads them via AJAX.  My "about" page, therefore, is located at /about/, but will load on the main page and will, once finished, utilize hash/hashbang links to enable back-button functionality.

Here's the problem I have: while a hash/hashbang link will be able to be used to link to a specific page via AJAX for users with JavaScript, if a user with JavaScript attempts to link someone without it to the page, the page cannot be loaded for that person using AJAX.

As such, I'd like to be able, if possible, to use .htaccess to redirect hash/hashbang-specified pages to the canonical link.  In other words, the exact opposite of what [this contributer was trying to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999969/).

> http://example.com/#!about --> http://example.com/about/

Is it possible with .htaccess, or otherwise *without* JavaScript?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this on server side. Because the part of the url after # is not included in the request sent to the server.

Comment: I sort of thought that may be the case :<
Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late to the party on this one, but i'm looking into this too. Since your url already contains the #!, as opposed to #, you can actually do this. Google will fetch

```
http://example.com/#!about
```

as

```
http://example.com?_escaped_fragment_about
```

Therefore, if you use a redirect 301 on that, and use javascript to redirect the user only version of the page, you have practically reached your desired result.

I realise you asked for a no-javascript solution, but i figure that was for reasons of SEO. For more information, please see [this](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) page  by google.

EDIT:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

Some more on meta refresh [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

It:

```
1) Does not require javascript!
```

-

```
2) Can be Seo friendly!
```

-

```
3) Works with bookmarks and history (etc.)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's actually not too bad of an idea for SEO purposes.  Not my intention, though (the reason I asked for non-JS is because I wanted to make the site friendly for JS-less users - I don't need to redirect users with JS, as they'll get the AJAX page, but without a non-JS redirect, users without JS, when linked to http://example.com/#!about, would instead just see the home page.  Rather unfortunate it's not doable, but I suppose that's the price of using AJAX.

Comment: how would the users be requesting the url? If theyre heading from bookmarks then just give them the JS-free link? Its a shame PHP cant handle this..

Comment: Well, from bookmarks, or from other people linking them (directly or otherwise). I think what I'm going to do is simply try to minimize links that can't be parsed without JavaScript by providing a "bookmark this page"/"link to this page" link, which will use the non-AJAX link.  It won't solve the problem, but it should help minimize its occurrences.

Comment: I just thought of this, and it is so simple... Meta redirects, in combination with an 301 redirect on the crawlable version i mentioned.  i'll update the answer...